# How to make Json.Net deserialize without error if the entire value is null

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've already seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813055/how-to-handle-null-empty-values-in-jsonconvert-deserializeobject). My question is about when the entire object is null.

```
MyClass x = null;
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x); // "\"null\""
x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json, serializationsettings);
```

That errors no matter what I put for `serializationSettings`.

Comment: because `"\"null\""` is not valid json. Maybe just check for this value before deserializing?

Comment: If you know for sure about this value ("\"null\""), why not to check it first and then only to deserialize it?

Comment: Are you getting any exception?