# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject issue with null values

Tags: c#, sql-server, date-formatting, sqlbulkcopy

I am using a `SqlBulkCopy` from json data using C# and SQL Server 2016.

The original string is: `"1979-09-30T23:00:00.000+0000"`

But when copied into the SQL Server table using `SqlBulkCopy`, the string becomes               `"01/10/1979 00:00:00"`

I am using `varchar(100)` as data type for this column.

I tried with `date`, `datetime` and `datetimeoffset` data types, but I was getting conversion errors each time.

```
create table Employees(
matricule  nvarchar(20),
pname  nvarchar(100),
birthdate  varchar(100),
hiredate varchar(100))
```

-- I tried with date, datetime and datetimeoffset data types, but I was getting conversion errors each time.
    )

How to do in order to preserve the original data?

After analysis I found the issue root
the Json has null values in date field 
the date is json is like this

> "field_date_name":null

the json serializer is getting error with this field

```
public static void BulkCopy(DataTable myDataTable)
{           
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["2"].ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
        {
            foreach (DataColumn c in myDataTable.Columns)
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(c.ColumnName, c.ColumnName);

            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = myDataTable.TableName;

            try
            {
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(myDataTable);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.Message);                        
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the method calling it

```
public static void Employee()
        {
            try
            {                
                DataTable MyTable = Clapi.GetApiData(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("api_employe"), "imp_Employees").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                log.Info(String.Format("Table: {0} Count {1}", MyTable.TableName, MyTable.Rows.Count));
                Cldb.BulkCopy(MyTable);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

// and here GetApiData

```
public static async Task<DataTable> GetApiData(string Url ,string TableName)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, Url);
                var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                var contents = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var Mytable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(contents);
                Mytable.TableName = TableName;
                return Mytable;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error("GetApiData; url="+Url+";TableName:"+TableName+ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Json data

> [{
>       "matricule": "0009",
>       "pname": "xxxx",
>       "birthdate": "1961-02-25T23:00:00.000+0000",
>       "hiredate": "1976-02-14T23:00:00.000+0000"
>     }]

After bulkcopy to sql server these 2 dates become

> "1961-02-25T23:00:00.000+0000" becomes 02/26/1961 00:00:00
>   "1976-02-14T23:00:00.000+0000" becomes 15/02/1976 00:00:00

I also tried with setting , but still getting error

> NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore

Comment: If it's a date, you should use date types. Please show the code that creates the datatable and populates it from Json. This is the place where things are happening, not on BulkCopy method

Comment: I updated my question adding the sql script creating the table: I tried with date,datetime and datetimeoffset data types, but I was getting conversion errors each time.
)

Comment: The dates coming from json through a webapi have this format "2020-05-07T10:58:07.812Z"

Comment: I mean the code that creates the `System.Data.DataTable myDataTable` and populates it from JSON. I believe the problem is there

Comment: I already posted the code in my question (the c# code) above

Comment: You didn't, the code you posted is a method that receives DataTable myDataTable, but where does myDataTable comes from?

Comment: right, I posted the method calling that method at the end of my question, thanks

Comment: Put a break point before calling bulkCopy, and inspect the DataTable, please show column names and colum types. Also please inspect the data, edit your question to include what you found

Comment: All the data from json are coming as string, the problem is that json deserilisation assign data type based on the first row

Comment: Could you post the JSON so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Added to the end of the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213355/discussion-between-kemal-al-gazzah-and-jesus-lopez).

Comment: Problem solved! please see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `JsonSerializationSettings` with `DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc` then declare table date columns as `datetime` data type.

```
public static async Task<DataTable> GetApiData(string Url, string TableName)
{
    try
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, Url);
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        var contents = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
        };
        var Mytable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(contents, settings);
        Mytable.TableName = TableName;
        return Mytable;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error("GetApiData; url=" + Url + ";TableName:" + TableName + ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution and help, I figured out about the root of the problem, it is because of the value=null in a date field coming in Json, I asked the API supplier to replace it by a the date "1900/01/01",

Answer (score 0):

you're probably using DateTimeOffset in your code.

DateTimeOffset = DateTime+Offset(from UTC)

the difference probably is a cause of the offset between the client and server (two different zones)

if you are using DateTime you won't have this issue.

1) first try to debug your code to see that if the value that is going to be saved in the database is the same as the value saved.

2) So your data is already representing Client's Local date and time. Just cast it to DateTime and you will get the client's local Date and time.

more [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.utcnow?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: the data is coming from an external source (API)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. DB had null values and the DeserializeObject was throwing error not being able to convert null value to datetime, even though my model was setup as nullable DateTime.

This fixed the issue for me:

```
var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
};
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(return_data, jsonSettings);
```

I actually found the solution in the question asked here.

[How to handle null/empty values in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813055/how-to-handle-null-empty-values-in-jsonconvert-deserializeobject)

It did not work for the person posting the question, but worked in my situation.